# %in% Change in dplyr package in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a df in the following structure:

```
Case.No     Device.Phone.Number     Repair.Code
123         111-111-1111            RA10  
234         222-222-2222            RA21
345         111-111-1111            RA99
456         333-333-3333            RA01
567         222-222-2222            RA47
...         ...                     ...
789         333-333-3333            RA90
```

There are some 70 more columns, but not of interest for this question.

I am analyzing data of repeat callers (entries with the same Device.Phone.Number associated to them). My current method to subset this data from the df is:

```
library("plyr",  lib.loc="~/R/R-3.2.2/library")
Call.Count <- count(df$Device.Phone.Number)
Repeat.Calls <- Call.Count[Call.Count$freq > 1, ]
numbers <- Repeat.Calls[1:nrow(Repeat.Calls),1]
Repeat.Device <- df[df$Device.Phone.Number %in% numbers, ]
```

I would prefer to use the package `dplyr` throughout the script, but my use of `%in%` yields a dataframe with 0 obs if I use the `count` function from `dplyr` instead of from `plyr`.

Question: How can I avoid this issue? My script would be much more efficient if I could implement `dplyr` from the beginning.

As an aside, I am aware that `dplyr::count` uses "n" instead of "freq"

I have attached `dplyr` and changed my syntax as @Konrad prescribed.

```
Call.Count <- count(Clean.CRM, Device.Phone.Number)
Repeat.Calls <- Call.Count[Call.Count$n > 1, ]
numbers <- Repeat.Calls[1:nrow(Repeat.Calls),1]
Repeat.Device <- All.CRM[All.CRM$Device.Phone.Number %in% numbers, ]
```

But now using `%in%` while `dplyr` is attached does not function.

Comment: My guess would be you're getting caught by dplyr's atypical subsetting rules. What is `class(numbers)`? Is it a vector or a "tbl_df"?

Comment: @Thomas - `class(numbers)` returns `[1] "tbl_df"     "data.frame"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are encountering dplyr's irregularities. Its standard operating object is a "tbl_df" rather than the more common "data.frame". (This is the class of object returned by `dplyr::count()`.) It is often said that "tbl_df" is just a data.frame, which is true, but it plays by very different rules. You are encountering one of them here.

The difference is that tbl_df's subsetting/extraction rules do not set `drop = TRUE` whereas the `[` method for a standard data.frame does. To see the difference:

```
mtcars[, "mpg", drop = TRUE]  # a vector
mtcars[, "mpg", drop = FALSE] # a one-column data.frame
dplyr::tbl_df(mtcars)[,"mpg"] # a one-column "tbl_df"
```

Applying `[` to a tbl_df does the latter. In your case, this means `numbers` is a data.frame/tbl_df rather than a vector. `%in%` applied to a data.frame does weird things, specifically the weird thing you're currently experiencing.

The solution is to extract the first (and only) column from `numbers` via `numbers[[1]]`. If you change your last line of code to:

```
Repeat.Device <- All.CRM[All.CRM$Device.Phone.Number %in% numbers[[1]], ]
```

It should work nicely.

Comment: Excellent!!! Thank you very much for your answer and even more for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Well, `dplyr::count` is different from `plyr::count`. And neither is to be used in the way that you’re using it here (though `plyr` accepts this usage; `dplyr` doesn’t).

In **plyr**, you should write:

```
Call.Count <- count(df, 'Device.Phone.Number')
```

In **dplyr**, you *must* write:

```
Call.Count <- count(df, Device.Phone.Number)
# or
Call.Count <- count_(df, 'Device.Phone.Number')
```

Comment: Thank you, @konrad - I am aware of the syntax you mention for `dplyr::count` because I use that function elsewhere. But even still, using `%in%` for the `Repeat.Device` assignment does not work as I expect. That is the issue I am hoping to resolve.

Comment: @el_dewey if the line with `%in%` is your problem, you should correct the syntax errors you have that occur before that. That is, use valid syntax for `dplyr::count` as Konrad shows here before you try to use `%in%`.